# Div horizontal scrolling with perfectScrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I am having some issues making a div expand 100% of it's content, within another div, and then scrolling said div with perfectScrollbar.

Is there something I am missing here with the width attributes and overflow settings?

Basically all the `A` links should be in one line, no line breaks. So that the scrollbar can scroll left and right.

http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/2gp8Lmjy/

**CSS**

```
#header-compbar{background:transparent url(http://beeskneesfx.com/images/primus/blue/misc/black80opacity.png) repeat left top;clear:left;width:1005px;height:60px;overflow:hidden;}
#header-compbar h4{line-height:1.2em;float:left;height:40px;margin:0;padding:10.8px 10px}
#header-compbar .competition{display:inline-block;float:left;height:60px;text-decoration:none;font-size:11px;color:#bebebe;padding:0 10px}
#header-compbar .competition img{float:left;display:block;margin-top:5px;height:50px}
#header-compbar .competition .comptitle{display:block;font-weight:700;font-size:12px;line-height:1em;white-space:nowrap;margin:9px 0 3px 50px}
#header-compbar .competition .comptopic{display:block;line-height:1em;white-space:nowrap;margin:0 0 3px 50px}
#header-compbar .competition .compdate{display:block;font-style:italic;line-height:1em;white-space:nowrap;margin:0 0 0 50px}
#header-compbar-container { width: auto;height: 60px;position: absolute;white-space: nowrap;}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="header-compbar">
        <div id="header-compbar-container">
            <h4><a href="./competitions.php#competition_voting_link">FEATURED<br />ARTIST</a></h4>

            <a href="./competitions.php?mode=view&amp;id=947&amp;" class="competition">
                <img src="http://beeskneesfx.com/images/primus/blue/misc/nex.png" alt="" />
                <span class="comptitle">Nexolous ( Logan Edwards )</span>
                <span class="comptopic">Age n/a</span>
                <span class="compdate">Photographer / Digital Artist</span>
            </a>

            <a href="./competitions.php?mode=view&amp;id=947&amp;" class="competition">
                <img src="http://beeskneesfx.com/images/primus/blue/misc/nex.png" alt="" />
                <span class="comptitle">Nexolous ( Logan Edwards )</span>
                <span class="comptopic">Age n/a</span>
                <span class="compdate">Photographer / Digital Artist</span>
            </a>

            <a href="./competitions.php?mode=view&amp;id=947&amp;" class="competition">
                <img src="http://beeskneesfx.com/images/primus/blue/misc/nex.png" alt="" />
                <span class="comptitle">Nexolous ( Logan Edwards )</span>
                <span class="comptopic">Age n/a</span>
                <span class="compdate">Photographer / Digital Artist</span>
            </a>

            <a href="./competitions.php?mode=view&amp;id=947&amp;" class="competition">
                <img src="http://beeskneesfx.com/images/primus/blue/misc/nex.png" alt="" />
                <span class="comptitle">Nexolous ( Logan Edwards )</span>
                <span class="comptopic">Age n/a</span>
                <span class="compdate">Photographer / Digital Artist</span>
            </a>

            <a href="./competitions.php?mode=view&amp;id=947&amp;" class="competition">
                <img src="http://beeskneesfx.com/images/primus/blue/misc/nex.png" alt="" />
                <span class="comptitle">Nexolous ( Logan Edwards )</span>
                <span class="comptopic">Age n/a</span>
                <span class="compdate">Photographer / Digital Artist</span>
            </a>

            <a href="./competitions.php?mode=view&amp;id=947&amp;" class="competition">
                <img src="http://beeskneesfx.com/images/primus/blue/misc/nex.png" alt="" />
                <span class="comptitle">Nexolous ( Logan Edwards )</span>
                <span class="comptopic">Age n/a</span>
                <span class="compdate">Photographer / Digital Artist</span>
            </a>



        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you looking something like this??  http://jsfiddle.net/2gp8Lmjy/6/

Comment: please when you are using fiddle and asking about an external plugin, please include that plugin as well in the external resources section.

Comment: Hmm, could be browser specific issue too, as that looks exactly the same, not even a pixel off from my example.

Comment: @Sai That is completely a optional, and shouldn't be part of the issue. The issue is CSS and JS here. You can click the HTML link and find out the same information.

Comment: is it not solved, or i didnt get  you what you are saying??

Comment: ok if perfectScrollbar is not relevant then, if I understand it right, you want the inner div to be 100% width/height of the outer div width/height. Yet you have contents inside the inner div which is going to overflow the width/height. Am I assuming correct here?

Comment: if I asssumed right, then you want the scrollbar that will appear not to interfere with your styling of inner div?

Comment: @Sai The master div should be a container. The inner div should span the the width **only** of the content within it. Then the outer div should scroll the horizontal length of the inner div. Currently the content is pushed to a new line, and the scrollbar doesn't scroll from what I'm seeing if I force it to have a greater width manually, so maybe perfectScrollbar is having issues with the content actually as well.

Comment: If anything, just getting the A tags to be in one line (no line breaks) would solve a lot. I could then ditch perfect scrollbar and use a normal animation or something.